# Problem with sending a value from child component to parent component using MudDialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I have a problem with sending data from a child component to a parent component while using MudBlazor.

**(Child component)**
<OknoDialogowe_Zatwierdzenie_Wybor_Daty>

```
public class UserData
{
    public DateTime wybranadata { get; set; }
}


private void Submit() {

    var data = new UserData
        {
            wybranadata = WybranaData,
        };

    MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(data));
    //  Wykonaj?.Invoke(); 
 
}
void Cancel(){
    MudDialog.CancelAll();
    //Ukryj?.Invoke();
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
public class UserData
{
    public DateTime wybranadata { get; set; }

}
...

var dane = await DialogService.ShowAsync<OknoDialogowe_Zatwierdzenie_Wybor_Daty>("Confirm", parameters);

var wynik = await dane.Result;
if (!wynik.Cancelled)
{
    var wyswietl = wynik.Data as UserData;
    if ( wyswietl != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(wyswietl.wybranadata);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("empty :(");
    }
 ;
```

How can I send data using as a class from <OknoDialogowe_Zatwierdzenie_Wybor_Daty> to the main component?
I still receive value "empty" :(

Comment: Examining MudBlazor docs, I see nothing obviously wrong with your code. Maybe others will spot a flow. You could try extending your code and producing a minimal example showing the code not working using https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet

Comment: I got error:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `IDialogService.GetReturnValueAsync<T>()` to return the UserData object from the dialog, instead of `wynik.Data as UserData;`

```cs
if (!wynik.Cancelled)
{
    var wyswietl = await dialog.GetReturnValueAsync<UserData>();
    if ( wyswietl != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(wyswietl.wybranadata);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("empty :(");
    }
}
```